# Check IP address off a list using ksh/bash

Tags: bash, scripting, logfile, shell, ksh

I have a list (text file) with the following data:

```
app1 example1.google.com   
app2 example2.google.com  
dev1 device1.google.com  
cell1 iphone1.google.com
```

I want to check the ip address of the URLs/hostnames and update the text file with the gathered ip. Example:

```
app1 example1.google.com 192.168.1.10  
app2 example2.google.com 192.168.1.55  
dev1 device1.google.com 192.168.1.53  
cell1 iphone1.google.com 192.168.1.199
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dig` to get the IP (but the domains must exist). Not tested for IPv6.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
while read name url ; do
    ip=$(dig -4 $url | grep '^[^;]' | grep -o '\([0-9]*[.:]\)\+[0-9.:]*$')
    printf '%s %s %s\n' "$name" "$url" "$ip"
done < data.txt
```

Comment: `dig` without record type does `A` query anyway, so no IPv6 to be expected. You would need to have it run with `AAAA` and then of course the regex wouldn't match.

Comment: It is not a good idea to parse `dig` output that way, far too much fragile. `dig` output is for humans, not computers. You should at least restrict things using `+short` or `+noall +ans`. Newer versions of `dig` have a `+yaml` option to get output in a structured way. That would be the best option for any meaningful post treatment.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two columns in the file, this might help:

`awk '{"dig +short " $2 | getline ip ; print $1, $2, ip}' file`

First we run a subshell (not really a good idea to run this for zillions of records) and in it a "dig +short" (the shortest possibility which came to my mind to get IP address only) with the FQDN of a machine (found in the second column). Then we print all the original columns and the new one too (with the IP address). Output can be redirected to a new file with a single `>`. I wouldn't consider "safe" to edit original files.